# Can we use connect by clause and listagg function together

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have a column with city values separated by ## and group name. I want to sort the text column in alphabetical order

Issue:

```
group   | values
group1  | jammu##bhopal##chandigardh
group2  | Mumbai##kolkatta
group3  | bangalore
```

Expected result

```
group   | values
group1  | bhopal##chandigardh##jammu
group2  | kolkatta##Mumbai
group3  | bangalore
```

I have tried below code

```
select group,listagg(city,'#') within group (order by city asc) as city
from (
      select group, regexp_substr(city,'[^##+',1, LEVEL) as city
     from (
           select group,city from city_group
          )
     connect by regexp_substr(city,'[^##+',1, LEVEL) us not null)
group by group
```

The code runs forever and yields no result.

Comment: Can you please, recreate your example from scratch and post an actual query? It seems like you edited your actual query without testing it, this makes it harder to reproduce your problem. For example: (1) `group` is a reserved word and can't be used as a column name, (2) `us not null` is not a valid code, (3) you have an unmatched, unescaped bracket in your regex.

Comment: It's a terrible mistake to store delimiter separated values in a column inside a table. Inspite of encountering problems  frequently, there still are  folks who have an inclination towards using this precarious design to store data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code will be useful to you.

```
-- Data preparation

CREATE TABLE CITY_GROUP (GROUPS VARCHAR2(100), VALUE VARCHAR2(4000));

INSERT INTO CITY_GROUP VALUES('group1','jammu##bhopal##chandigardh');

INSERT INTO CITY_GROUP VALUES('group2','mumbai##kolkatta');

INSERT INTO CITY_GROUP VALUES('group3','bangalore');

-- Your query

SELECT
    GROUPS,
    LISTAGG(CITY, '##') WITHIN GROUP(
        ORDER BY
            CITY
    ) AS CITY
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            GROUPS   AS GROUPS,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(VALUE, '[^##]+', 1, LEVEL) AS CITY
        FROM
            CITY_GROUP
        CONNECT BY
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(VALUE, '[^##]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    )
GROUP BY
    GROUPS;
```

**Ouptut**

[image: Output]

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Here is the [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=12b9bc7c98c58b7b041c902be0b290e7)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a little `JOIN` so your code really runs forever. Pay attention to lines #10 - 12; that's essential in your case.

```
SQL> with test (c_group, c_values) as
  2    (select 'group1', 'jammu##bhopal##chandigardh' from dual union all
  3     select 'group2', 'mumbai##kolkatta'           from dual union all
  4     select 'group3', 'bangalore'                  from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    (select c_group,
  8            regexp_substr(c_values, '[^##]+', 1, column_value) col
  9     from test join
 10          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 11                              connect by regexp_substr(c_values, '[^##]+', 1, level) is not null
 12                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist)) on 1 = 1
 13    )
 14  select c_group,
 15         listagg(col, '##') within group (order by col) result
 16  from temp
 17  group by c_group
 18  order by c_group;

C_GROU RESULT
------ ----------------------------------------
group1 bhopal##chandigardh##jammu
group2 kolkatta##mumbai
group3 bangalore

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to look for the code of lines that you highlighted but was unable to understand. Can you please explain what is happening.

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't use it, then Oracle performs Cartesian product (of all values in C_GROUP column with all rows (split values from the C_VALUES column) and - if there are a lot of rows in a table, it really never ends. If you used DISTINCT keyword in your query, a small sample table would be OK. But, for anything larger than that, it wouldn't help either as it just "virtually" fixes the problem. You have to join the source table values with the one that returns the LEVEL pseudocolumn based on each row's C_VALUES column, not *all* of them.

Comment: The regexp `[^##]+` doesn't really split on instances of `##`.  The second `#` in the character class is ignored as a duplicate as such even single `#` will act as delimiters.  This may not be what @PoojaGuru really wants.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL there are multiple ways to split strings into rows.  My preferred method is to use a recursive subfactored query (common table function or CTE for the non oracle crowd).

```
with city_group(grp, cities) as (
  select 'group1', 'jammu##bhopal##chandigardh' from dual union all
  select 'group2', 'Mumbai##kolkatta' from dual union all
  select 'group3', 'bangalore' from dual
), Recur (grp, cities, city, nxt, lst) as (
  -- Anchor Query
  select grp, cities
       , REGEXP_SUBSTR(cities,'(.+?)(##|$)',1,1,'',1)
       , REGEXP_INSTR(cities,'(.+?)(##|$)',1,1,1)
       , length(cities)
    from city_group

  -- Recursive part
  union all
  select grp, cities
       , REGEXP_SUBSTR(cities,'(.+?)(##|$)',nxt,1,'',1)
       , REGEXP_INSTR(cities,'(.+?)(##|$)',nxt,1,1)
       , lst
    from Recur
   where nxt <= lst
)
select grp
     , listagg(city,'##') within group (order by city)
  from Recur
  group by grp;
```

In the above code, the Anchor Query returns the first list element and sets up additional columns for iterating through the list of values. Specifically it returns the next starting search positions (`nxt`) and the position of the last (`lst`) character in the string used as a stopping condition for the recursive part.

Next in the recursive part of the query the subsequent list items are returned alont with the new `nxt` starting position.

Utilizing a moving starting position reduces the amount work needed to perform the string search as you move further into the list of values.

Now a word about the regular expression used.  Rather than the faulty `[^##]+` search string, which is functionally eqivalent to `[^#]+` and which can misidentify single `#` as string seperators, I've used a non greedy capture group `(.+?)` followed by a capture group that explicitly matches the string separator token or the end of string character `(##|$)`.  The `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function then uses the 6th parameter indicate that the 1st capture group contains the value that should be returned while the last parameter of the `REGEXP_INSTR` function indicate that the character position following the matched substring should be returned.

As a final bonus solution, if your DB has a recent version of APEX installed you can simply use the `APEX_STRING.split` table valued function like so:

```
with city_group(grp, cities) as (
  select 'group1', 'jammu##bhopal##chandigardh' from dual union all
  select 'group2', 'Mumbai##kolkatta' from dual union all
  select 'group3', 'bangalore' from dual
)
select grp
     , listagg(column_value,'##') within group (order by column_value)
  from city_group cg
  cross apply apex_string.split(cities,'##')
  group by grp;
```